# http 405 error in microsoft totorial - asp.net mvc

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

the "create" part is giving me a headache

StudentsController.cs

```
using ContosoUniversity.Data;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Controllers
{
    public class StudentsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SchoolContext _context;

        public StudentsController(SchoolContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Students.ToListAsync());
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var student = await _context.Students
                .Include(s => s.Enrollments)
                    .ThenInclude(e => e.Course)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(student);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EnrollmentDate,FirstMidName,LastName")] Student student)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.Add(student);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(student);
        }


 


    }
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Student

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>CreateView</h1>

<h4>Student</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstMidName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstMidName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstMidName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EnrollmentDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EnrollmentDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EnrollmentDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

if i remove "[HttpPost]" my model get's instantly updated and submitted with empty data and returns to index page

the link to actual tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-5.0#update-the-create-page

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution ... i need another method for HttpGet, with same name (create) ... still unsure why, and it works now, no 405 error

if someone has a good explanation, please

this is what i added in controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You create an `HttpGet` action in order to display the form to the user, then the user posts the form data to the controller `HttpPost` action. This is typical for an MVC application.  To update or create a record `HttpGet` is used to display the form, then `HttpPost` to receive the submitted data. The Post action is only used when the form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

since the action has an [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute you should add the same to the view, and replace form tag with an html helper

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Students", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
 .... and so on

}
```

and IMHO don' t use any bind at your post action, it is never a good idea

```
[HttpPost("~/students/create")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Student student)
```

Comment: tried this too, same problem, 405 again ...

Comment: @turpija can you post the controlle too pls?

Comment: i added whole StudentsController.cs in original post

Comment: @turpija Thanks, I updated my answer too, should be using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Students", FormMethod.Post))

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add `method="post"` to `<form></form>`.

```
<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstMidName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstMidName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstMidName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EnrollmentDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EnrollmentDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EnrollmentDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

So that the form will include a hidden input which name is `__RequestVerificationToken`,which contains the value of AntiForgeryToken.When form submit,the token will be passed to Create action.

Comment: this didn't work, problem is probably somewhere else